# Order of ifs altering final result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

These two seemingly identical pieces of code are giving me vastly different results.
The first one gets timer to match sessionUserInput:

```
handleSession(event){
    const id= event.target.id;
    let breakvar= this.state.breakSession;
    let sessionvar= this.state.session;
    let isPaused=this.state.isPaused;
    let intervalBegan=this.state.intervalBegan;
    let sessionUserInput=this.state.session;



    if(isPaused && id==="break-increment" && breakvar<=59){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            breakSession: this.state.breakSession +1,
            breakValue:this.state.breakValue + 60}))}

    else if (isPaused && id==="break-decrement" && breakvar>1){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            breakSession: this.state.breakSession -1,
            breakValue:this.state.breakValue - 60}))}

    else if(isPaused && id==="session-increment" && sessionvar <=59){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            session: this.state.session +1,
            timer: this.state.timer + 60}))}

    else if (isPaused && id==="session-decrement" && sessionvar>1){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            session: this.state.session -1,
            timer:this.state.timer - 60}))}


    if(isPaused && intervalBegan && id==="session-decrement"){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            timer: (sessionUserInput * 60) - 60,
            intervalBegan: false}))}


    else if(isPaused && intervalBegan && id==="session-increment"){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            timer: (sessionUserInput * 60) + 60,
            intervalBegan: false}))}



    else if(id === "reset"){
        clearInterval(this.Interval);
        this.setState((state) => ({
            session: 25,
            timer: 1500,
            breakSession: 5,
            breakValue:300,
            isPaused: true
        }))
    }}
```

While this one, while neatier, makes timer exactly one minute smaller than timer:

```
handleSession(event){
    const id= event.target.id;
    let breakvar= this.state.breakSession;
    let sessionvar= this.state.session;
    let isPaused=this.state.isPaused;
    let intervalBegan=this.state.intervalBegan;
    let sessionUserInput=this.state.session;

    if(isPaused && intervalBegan && id==="session-increment"){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            timer: (sessionUserInput * 60) + 60,
            intervalBegan: false}))}

    else if(isPaused && intervalBegan && id==="session-decrement"){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            timer: (sessionUserInput * 60) - 60,
            intervalBegan: false}))}


    else if(isPaused && intervalBegan && id==="session-increment"){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            timer: (sessionUserInput * 60) + 60,
            intervalBegan: false}))}


    else if(isPaused && id==="break-increment" && breakvar<=59){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            breakSession: this.state.breakSession +1,
            breakValue:this.state.breakValue + 60}))}

    else if (isPaused && id==="break-decrement" && breakvar>1){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            breakSession: this.state.breakSession -1,
            breakValue:this.state.breakValue - 60}))}

    else if(isPaused && id==="session-increment" && sessionvar <=59){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            session: this.state.session +1,
            timer: this.state.timer + 60}))}

    else if (isPaused && id==="session-decrement" && sessionvar>1){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            session: this.state.session -1,
            timer:this.state.timer - 60}))}


    else if(id === "reset"){
        clearInterval(this.Interval);
        this.setState((state) => ({
            session: 25,
            timer: 1500,
            breakSession: 5,
            breakValue:300,
            isPaused: true
        }))
    }}
```

I don´t really see the difference between the two: the order and quality of checks seem the same to me. Any ideas on what´s causing this difference? Is it logical?

Comment: Have you debugged this code in dev tools? That is the quickest way to find this. Put a simple working solution up on the React Playground if you need help with that.

Comment: Well OK then - I can at least help with that. Here is the React Editor that allows you to create full React apps on line. Find it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are so many variables here, it is difficult to tell exactly the cause of the difference in results. But there are some things to notice here.

**1.**
First is that the order of the conditions is not the same across the two code samples. Since the various conditions are not all mutually exclusive, at least as far as I can tell with limited knowledge of your app, changing the order of conditions can change results when using `else if` statements. This is because only the code under the first condition that evaluates to `true` will be executed, so if two are true and the order is swapped, the result will change.

For example:

```
const a = true;
const b = false;

// 1.
if (a) {
    console.log("a only");
} else if (a || b) {
    console.log("a or b");
}

// 2.
if (a || b) {
    console.log("a or b");
} else if (a) {
    console.log("a only");
}
```

In the first of these examples, `"a only"` is logged, but in the second `"a or b"` is logged, and the difference in result is due only to flipping the order of conditions.

**2.**
Second is that the first example uses two separate `if/else` statements, while the second example uses only one. Thus in the first two conditions can evaluate to true and have their code executed, while in the second example, only the code of one true condition will ever be executed.

For example:

```
const a = true;
const b = false;

// 1.
if (a) {
    console.log("a only");
} else if (a || b) {
    console.log("a or b");
}

// 2.
if (a) {
    console.log("a only");
}
if (a || b) {
    console.log("a or b");
}
```

In the first of these examples, only `"a only"` is logged, while in the second, both `"a only"` and `"a or b"` are logged.